# Object can't find descendent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, descendant

I'm writing a class to write XLS files called "BravoManagementXlsReport". It's currently sitting in the following directory:

[image]

All the other reports all inherit from `xls_report`, so I did the same.

```
class BravoManagementXlsReport < XlsReport
  attr_reader :file_name
  ...
end
```

When I run the worker I get:

```
2014-02-24T16:22:58Z 18204 TID-ovbv17qdg WARN: uninitialized constant BravoManagementXlsReport
```

I thought I should restart the workers, but that didn't work, so I restarted the Rails server but that didn't work either. In the console I tried:

```
[2] toolkit »  ManagementXlsReport // this returns the object
=> ManagementXlsReport < XlsReport
[3] toolkit »  BravoManagementXlsReport // this is obviously not finding it
NameError: uninitialized constant BravoManagementXlsReport

[1] toolkit »  XlsReport.descendants // this returns everything but the new file
=> [
  [0] SocioeconomicDevelopmentXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [1] EnterpriseDevelopmentXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [2] PreferentialProcurementXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [3] IntermediaryBillXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [4] ScorecardXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [5] TrainingProgramXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [6] GeneralXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [7] EmploymentEquityXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [8] ManagementXlsReport < XlsReport,
  [9] SkillsDevelopmentXlsReport < XlsReport
]
```

Is there something I am missing? I tried seeing if I had misspelled something but I can't see it.

Comment: Maybe try a project wide search for one of the other reports and see if you need to register it somewhere first. I can really recommend [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) for searching code. You could for example do `ack -i ManagementXlsReport` and see if you get results besides the class definition itself.

Comment: Yeah i did a system wide search just in case there was a security feature of something. the only other places the descendants are called are in the specs.

Comment: You could also search for the filenames in case the reports need to be required somewhere else.

Comment: That got me excited it was an idea i hadn't tried. unfortunately not so. this is mind blowingly strange!?!

Comment: Ok so the first step in debugging would be to find out where these reports actually get instantiated. Did you find that out yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was going on. The path was not being loaded by rails. In the application config file i found this. i think its just bad legacy code that got me confused.

```
# These are imported so that the elements are downloadable to excel
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/reports/xls_report.rb"
[:employment_equity, :management, :skills_development, :enterprise_development, :preferential_procurement, :socioeconomic_development, :general, :training_program, :scorecard, :intermediary_bill].each do |file|
  require "#{Rails.root}/lib/reports/#{file}_xls_report.rb"
end
```

So i just replaced it with a auto path loader:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{Rails.root}/lib/reports )
```

now it works just fine :) thanks so much for all your help this! hope this ends up helping someone else.